# Как сделать выборку двух столбцов таблицы в один option

Tags: sql, post, php, select, mysql

Или почему не правильно? А как правильно?

```
$qwer =("SELECT * FROM  ведомость");
                $sql = mysql_query($qwer) or die(mysql_error());    
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
                echo  "<select name='group'>"."<option >"."№"."</option>";
                do   
                {

                echo "<option value=" .$row['группа','дисциплина'].">".$row['группа','дисциплина']."</option>";
                }
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql));
                echo "</select>";
```

Comment: да что у вас за болезнь то с этим `do {} while ()` ???

 * расширение mysql устарело
 * в $row - одномерный массив, значит $row['группа'].','.$row['дисциплина']

Comment: что не подходит ?

Comment: Знаете, ведь в php ещё и переменные можно на киррилице обзывать.
Только это плохо. И за это тот, кто будет поддерживать после вас работу ваших программ, закопает ваши руки отдельно от головы :)

> "Пишите код так, как будто
> сопровождать его будет склонный к
> насилию психопат, который знает, где
> вы живете". (с) Макконнелл,
> "Совершенный код".

Comment: вообщем принять бы ваш комментарий за ответ

Comment: почему не нравится ему так то?=( хочу чтобы и пробелы передавались
>echo '<option value='.{$ro['дисциплина'].', >'.$ro['группа']}.'>'.{$ro['дисциплина'].', >'.$ro['группа']}.'</option>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, что вы с этим дальше делать будете, но можно конкатенировать два столбца в один:

```
SELECT concat(группа,' ',дисциплина) as group_disc FROM  ведомость
```

Comment: @msi ок. А за чем? Перечитайте вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вообще, если Вам нужна выборка по двум столбцам всего, то и в запросе лучше пишите только то, нужно + ID (SELECT группа,дисциплина,id FROM ведомость). А в option в value прописывайте ID. И я надеюсь это просто пример и в БД все на латинице...

Comment: т.е as id....?

Comment: id так и вообще нету. я вас не понял=(

Comment: <?
    $qwer =("SELECT id,group,discipline FROM  vedomost");
    $sql = mysql_query($qwer) or die(mysql_error());    
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    if(!empty($row)):
?>
<? foreach($row as $value):?>
    <select name='group'>
        <option value=<?=$value['id'];?> >№.<?=$value['группа'].",".$value['дисциплина'];?>    </option>";
    </select>
<?endforeach;?>
<?else:?>
    <h4> Какой-нибудь Error</h4>
<?endif;?>

Как-то так на скорую руку. И да short_tags должны быть включены...

Comment: Как нет ID?)) А primary key тогда что? Или его вообще нет? Если нет, то следует добавить в таблицу идентификатор, назначить ему primary key и AI галочку поставить.

Comment: первичный группа

Comment: А группа это чего вообще? Если это varchar, то надо бы в отдельную табличку и подсоединять.

Answer (score 0):

Выборка по столбцам column1 и column2:

```
SELECT `column1`,`column2` FROM `tableName`
```